# Prove that line segments are parallel.

Tags: geometry, self-learning

Prove using slope of lines that line segment joining the midpoint of $\overline { AB}$ and $\overline{AC}$ in $\Delta ABC$ is parallel to $\overline {BC.}$

Need to prove using slope of lines means I can prove slope of both the lines are equal, So they are parallel.

But here i don't know how to assume coordinates of all the points.

Comment: http://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Triangles/The-line-segment-joining-the-midpoints-of-two-sides-of-a-triangle.lesson

Comment: @labbhattacharjee It is not proved using slope of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By locating your coordinate axes with origin at B and the x-axis pointing along BC, you can assume that B has coordinates (0,0) and C had coordinates (c,0) for some c and A has coordinates (a,h) for some a and h.

Then the midpoint of BA is (a/2, h/2) and the midpoint of CA is ( (a+c)/2, h/2 ). The line joining these two points then has slope zero, which is the same as the slope of BC.

Comment: Yes, how can i forget about shifting of origin, thanks i got it.

Comment: @Freddy It is also totally possible to assume $A=(A_x, A_y)$ and similarly for $B$ and $C$. The math will certainly be much more tedious, but you will arrive at the same conclusion.